# Return a Point value in Java

Tags: java, return, point

How do I return the value of a Point function.
Example:

```
public Point myFunction(int x, int y) {
    return ???; // Want to return X and Y as a point.
}
```

I have no idea how the return should look.
Help please.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
   public Point myFunction(int x, int y) {
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
```

What kind of point are you trying to make?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a constructor that accepts x and y:

`return new Point(x,y);`